# Regex: match ":" and "-" but don't match "I-"

Tags: php, regex

```
Ohare:Montrose:I-290 Circle:IL:IL
Ohare-Montrose-I_290-Circle-IL-IL
EB:Kennedy Expy:O'Hare:IL-43 (Harlem Ave):IL:IL

NB:I-894/US-45:Hale Interchange:Zoo Interchange:WI:IL
```

NB
I-894/US-45
Hale
Interchange
Zoo Interchange
WI
IL

```
WB:Indiana-East-West:Eastpoint:Middlebury:IN:25:IL
```

WB
Indiana-East-West
Eastpoint
Middlebury
IN
25
IL

Trying to extract words from two different sources that use different conventions.

Using regex for that, I cannot create one regex that deals with both options.

If I try to extract using `:` or `-` then the first one gets extracted as

```
Ohare, Montrose, I, 290 Circle, IL, IL
```

How can I get a regex to split on `:` or `-` but ignore `I-` or ignore 'IL-', 'US-', 'Indiana-East-West' and many other that I may find?

What I have so far but not working as I want
[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/xO2vS6/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this negative lookbehind regex:

```
(?:(?:IL?|US)-|Indiana-East-West)(*SKIP)(*F)|[:-]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xO2vS6/2)

**Example Code:**

```
$s = 'NB:I-894/US-45:Hale Interchange:Zoo Interchange:WI:IL';
print_r(preg_split('/(?:(?:IL?|US)-|Indiana-East-West)(*SKIP)(*F)|[:-]/' , $s));
Array
(
    [0] => NB
    [1] => I-894/US-45
    [2] => Hale Interchange
    [3] => Zoo Interchange
    [4] => WI
    [5] => IL
)
```

Comment: Although the code works I need to be able to exclude I- and in some cases US- and Indiana-West-East and so on. Can I exclude the whole thing and not be linked to the - ?

Comment: It can be handled but I need to see your sample input and expected output. Can you edit the question and provide it?

Comment: Unfortunately its not working as I would like. I'm getting the catastrophic backtracking error. Isn't there another way of doing it. I only need to match specific chars and ignore other pairs of chars. The regex u provided seems a bit too complicated.

Comment: It worked with your provided sample input. If you provide me a sample for which it doesn't work then I can surely suggest something else.

Comment: On the second input it fails to extract the last two IL separately

Comment: If you mean `Ohare-Montrose-I_290-Circle-IL-IL` then by definition you wanted to avoid split on `-` if it is **preceded** by `IL` and hyphen in `IL-IL` is preceded by `IL`

Comment: You're right. That's forcing me to rethink everything since I don't think I'll be able to extract properly from those two sources. l'll have to do it separately for each of them. Thanks you for your help.